# How were the Greek city-states "unified"?

Tags: ancient-greece

There was a sentence that said: "Though the Greek city-states were unified to some extent in the face of an external threat, as that threat waned, conflicts between the city-states made a resurgence.". Why the heck they were unified while they are actually independent sovereign cities which serve as the centers of political, economic and cultural life over their contiguous territories ? Even they fought one another.

Comment: I cannot support re-open until the reasons the question were closed are addressed. Where is this sentence? Who wrote it? What was their bias/intent/approach? [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Answer (score 6):

Think of a village of feuding farming families out in the wilderness. They are all relatives, but they are always squabbling, and even get into violent fights with each other over property lines and stolen cattle.

But when they are threatened by an outlaw gang, they (mostly) (temporarily) cooperate until the gang is run off. (I say "mostly" because one or two family wind up supporting the outlaws.) Note that they frequently don't actually unify, they just --sometimes -- work for a time under one leader.

Then they return to the feuding.

This, in small, is a pretty good model of the ancient Greeks.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Mark Olson. Have a nice day :D